# Is there a way to exit the copy con command without using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I've seen people exit copy con using `Crtl+C` or `Crtl+Z` but I wonder if there is a way to do the same thing without keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from hitting <kbd>F6</kbd> which inserts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> most other keys/key-combinations (not shortcuts) are usually destined to the (redirected) output.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> abort the copy command. 
<kbd>F11</kbd> toggles full screen

> cite from doskey /? help
>   UP and DOWN ARROWS recall commands; ESC clears command line; F7 displays
>   command history; ALT+F7 clears command history; F8 searches command
>   history; F9 selects a command by number; ALT+F10 clears macro definitions

Comment: Well I meant how to do it without using the keyboard

Comment: With **your** definition of a shortcut I can't argue. Is shift + any key also a shortcut?

Comment: You called it the "copy con" command, but it's really just the copy command.  You're copying *from* the con (console) to a named file.  Therefore, you need to send an EOF (end of file) marker to let the copy command know that it's finished.  That's what CTRL+Z is.  Since the console **is** the keyboard and screen, it doesn't really make sense that you would want to copy from the con without using the con.

Comment: Well no need to lecture me, but maybe @Mr.Magic has some touchless tricks he didn't tell us.

Comment: In case anyone else falls into this, I was (rightly or wrongly) using `copy con` in a Docker CLI and `ctrl+z` closed the CLI window and left the batch file in use and unaccessible. Using `F6` worked a treat to put the `^Z` into the batch file